# how i can send data post after load page in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I send post data after loading a page with jQuery?

For example

```
    $( "#target" ).click(function() {
      $('#thetag').load(page.php, function(){

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "page.php",
  data: {data: "hi world"},
  success: function(result) {
     console.log('good');
      }
});
    });
    });

</div id="thetag">
page.php

<?php echo $_POST['data'] ?> ==== 'hi world'
</div>
```

I need to load the `page.php` file after the click on `#target` and, at the same time, send that data via ajax post; showing the post data in `#thetag`

Comment: What result are you getting?  You've got what looks like an errant `/` in your opening div tag.  Is the code inside that div tag whats on page.php?  If that's the case, you should be seeing `hi world ==== 'hi world'` in the div.

Comment: what is current result? any errors , blank response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the data with your [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) request. Without more information it doesn't seem to make sense to make another request to same url

```
$('#thetag').load(page.php, {data: "hi world"}}
```

Comment: `.load` performs a `GET` request, not `POST`.

Comment: The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Comment: A little detail I've overlooked for years.